# How to make onPostExecute() or Json parsing work?

Tags: android, json, android-emulator

I am a beginner in Android, and I am writing a short program to download a JSON feed from URL and parse it. I use AsyncTask to do the downloading.

The doInBackground() part seems to work well. Then I set my breakpoint to onPostExecute(), it can even stop at `parseJSON(result)`, and 'result' is showing the correct json string downloaded. But when I try to step into `parseJSON(result)`, it will NOT step into the function correctly(either throw JSONException directly or go to some random lines within `parseJSON(result)`).

From DDMS log it's not showing any valuable information as well.

How might I find what the problem is? Is it because I used `onPostExecute()` incorrectly, or `parseJSON()` has some problem?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private listItem[] items;

    public class listItem {
        String title;
        String description;
        String imageHref;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        items = new listItem[50];

        new DownloadJsonFeed().execute("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10168342/facts.json");
    }

    private class DownloadJsonFeed extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                return downloadUrl(params[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Unable to retrieve json feed. URL may be invalid.";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                parseJSON(result);          // Here !!!!!!
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            is = conn.getInputStream();

            // Convert the InputStream into a string
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            is.close();
            return sb.toString();
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            } 
        }
    }

    private void parseJSON(String feed) throws JSONException {
            JSONObject json_obj = new JSONObject(feed);
            title = json_obj.getString("title");
            String rows = json_obj.getString("rows");

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(rows);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject tmp = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                items[i].title = tmp.getString("title");
                items[i].description = tmp.getString("description");
                items[i].imageHref = tmp.getString("imageHref");
            }
    }
```

Comment: any logcat info would be useful, if you have some?

Comment: First to troubleshoot I would take the contents of `parseJSON` and place them in place of `parseJSON(result)` in `onPostExecute()`. Have you tried this yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you didn't get the JSON array right. The `json_obj.getString` will give you an String instead an array.

Try to change as follows:

```
  private void parseJSON(String feed) throws JSONException {
            JSONObject json_obj = new JSONObject(feed);
            title = json_obj.getString("title");
            String rows = json_obj.getString("rows");

            JSONArray jArray = json_obj.getJSONArray("rows"); //<---- change this line
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject tmp = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                items[i].title = tmp.getString("title");
                items[i].description = tmp.getString("description");
                items[i].imageHref = tmp.getString("imageHref");
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Lazy. That is the problem! Although i do not know why it's affecting the function debugging. After i change it like you suggested, debug work well too.

Comment: Could depend on where your placed your breakpoint. Anyway, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

`JSONObject.getString()` will try to get String type value, but what you want is array type.